# Getting the error note of a formula with #NA in google sheets for a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I cant find any way of getting the error message of a failing formula (which actually gives more info that just the error code since this is always 7 for #NA). #NA could mean different things and I would like to be able to identify which cells have which type of #NA.

`getNote` does not work.

Is there a way?

Im using IMPORTXML(C1:C,"//@value")

[image]

but for example when I vlookup is failing this is the error message that I would like to retrieve

[image]

Comment: Maybe there are other ways of identifying the different #NA errors?

Comment: What are you passing to `getNote()`? As in, what's inside the `()`?

Comment: @Dan getNote() is a method of Class Range, it doesn't use any argument.

Comment: Can you provide the content of any of the cells you are referencing in your formula so that this can be reproduced?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a5LCi6Ito8XHi2cemwE_tFZ4OUzcQqdmf2SuRgV3Y2w/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2021-02-01:

As [mentioned by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396959/getting-the-error-note-of-a-formula-with-na-in-google-sheets-for-a-script/59412653#comment116703768_59412653), error messages can be retrieved in Sheets API via [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). This information can be found as part of the [ExtendedValue](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ExtendedValue), which corresponds to the property `effectiveValue` of the [cell data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData).

An example of a response could be the following one:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "errorValue": {
                      "type": "DIVIDE_BY_ZERO",
                      "message": "Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be zero."
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You could then use [Advanced Sheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to access this API via Apps Script. For example, if you wanted to retrieve the error message for cell `A1`, you could do the following:

```
function getErrorMessage(cellNotation = "A1") {
  const optionalArgs = {
    fields: "sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveValue))))",
    ranges: cellNotation
  }
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, optionalArgs);
  const errorMessage = response.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].effectiveValue.errorValue.message;
  return errorMessage;
}
```

Unfortunately, this cannot be used as a custom function since it requires user authorization (see [Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)).

#### Original answer:

As far as I know, there is no built-in function, no Apps Script tool <s>and no API method</s> that will retrieve this information.

If you think it would be considerably useful to have this functionality, you could consider creating a Feature Request in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191608).

As a workaround, you could create a custom function for each of the built-in functions you are using and use [try... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to retrieve whatever exceptions you get.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Im not very experienced but this would mean include the formula for the cell from the script and then catching the error if there is one.... but would this works for formulas that can change status like importxml which can take between second and several minutes to load? would is still work? The idea was actually more to check the status of a cell that already has a formula there before hand.... when I use importxml for api calls different cells might have loaded succesfully and others have different types of errors, not enough credits, api returned no results..

Comment: @reraisebob you cannot use built-in formulas in the script. What I proposed was writing a script function that would emulate the behaviour of the built-in functions you want to use and handle the exceptions that you might get.

Comment: When I had created a sample script, I noticed that the error message of formula can be retrieved using the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8a596d235205ba443452aeb510220477 Although unfortunately, in the current stage, this cannot still be achieved by only the built-in functions, I thought that when this information is added to your answer, it might be useful for other users.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your comment, it provides very valuable information. When I originally posted this answer, I totally missed that functionality from the API. I updated my answer in order to give this more visibility. If you think this could be improved, feel free to edit this answer or to post a new one.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for replying and adding the information. I think that your answer will be more useful for users.