# Read error description from a #N/A in a google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets, I have different scenarios that gives #N/A error but from interface I can see that the error is not exactly the same since the description is different from case to case.

As an example two formulas

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com"; "//asd")
```

and

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.comn"; "//asd")
```

gives both #N/A but first is "Empty value in the fetched document", the second is "unable to fetch".
Is there a way to distinguish the two cases from the script side? I would like to avoid to fetch using UrlFechApp because fetched URLs always have captcha and anti-bot pages when fetched.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396959/getting-the-error-note-of-a-formula-with-na-in-google-sheets-for-a-script/59412653#comment116703768_59412653) and [lamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59412653/14606045), error messages can be retrieved in Sheets API via [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). This information can be found as part of the [ExtendedValue](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ExtendedValue), which corresponds to the property `effectiveValue` of the [cell data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData).

An example of a response could be the following one:

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "errorValue": {
                      "type": "DIVIDE_BY_ZERO",
                      "message": "Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be zero."
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You could then use [Advanced Sheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to access this API via Apps Script. For example, if you wanted to retrieve the error message for cell `A1`, you could do the following:

```
function getErrorMessage(cellNotation) {
  const optionalArgs = {
    fields: "sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveValue))))",
    ranges: cellNotation
  }
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, optionalArgs);
  const errorMessage = response.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].effectiveValue.errorValue.message;
  const errorType = response.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0].effectiveValue.errorValue.type;
  Logger.log(errorType);
  Logger.log(errorMessage);
}

function main() {
  getErrorMessage("A1");
  getErrorMessage("A2");
}
```

#### Sample input:

[image: input1]
[image: input2]

#### Sample output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- When I tried your sample, both does return the same error. Not sure why it isn't the same with yours but the script output was exactly the same as sheets cell error message.

Unfortunately, this cannot be used as a custom function since it requires user authorization (see [Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)).